# Vim -- Stop curly braces navigation from leaving marks

Tags: vim

Curly When using curly braces navigation, `{`, `}`, to move between paragraph, overwrites the "last jump" mark (the one accessible via `''`). I would find it more useful if it left this mark untouched. Is there any way to configure vim like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `keepjumps` command. From `:h :keepjumps`:

```
                            *:keepj* *:keepjumps*
:keepj[umps] {command}
            Moving around in {command} does not change the |''|,
            |'.| and |'^| marks, the |jumplist| or the
            |changelist|.
            Useful when making a change or inserting text
            automatically and the user doesn't want to go to this
            position.
```

So in your case, you'd want

```
nnoremap } :keepjumps normal! }<cr>
nnoremap { :keepjumps normal! {<cr>
```

Or, if you want it to work for visual mode too (which your probably do):

```
xnoremap } :<C-u>keepjumps normal! gv}<cr>
xnoremap { :<C-u>keepjumps normal! gv{<cr>
```

Comment: Hmm. Looks promising, but this gives the error "E169: Command to recursive" when I press `{` or `}`.

Comment: @nijoakim Did you do `nmap` or `nnoremap`? That shouldn't be an issue as long as you do `nnoremap`.

Comment: @DJMacMayhem: I tried them both. I also copied the text exactly as you wrote it. Can you confirm it works for you?

Comment: @nijoakim Oh, I see what the issue is now. See my edit. Does that work for you?